# pandas DateOffset function

Tags: python, pandas

Is it normal that the following would return `True` ?

What would be the idea behind that ?

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
t + pd.DateOffset(month=1) == t
```

Comment: month replace it in Timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `months` instead `month` for add value `1`, not replace, thank you @splash58:

```
print (t + pd.DateOffset(months=1) == t)
False
```

**Details**:

```
print (t + pd.DateOffset(month=1))
2017-01-01 00:00:00

print (t + pd.DateOffset(months=1))
2017-02-01 00:00:00
```

If check [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
**kwds

    Temporal parameter that add to or replace the offset value.

    Parameters that add to the offset (like Timedelta):

        years
        months
        weeks
        days
        hours
        minutes
        seconds
        microseconds
        nanoseconds

    Parameters that replace the offset value:

        year
        month
        day
        weekday
        hour
        minute
        second
        microsecond
        nanosecond
```

Comment: month replaces it in Timestamp but months adds

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html

Comment: `t + pd.DateOffset(month=5)
Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: Don't mention it

Comment: @splash58 - Done ;)

Comment: So it's kind of an offset but not really...  it depends on the extra "s"..   that's quite a pitfall over what is a pure convention !!